# W3TC: some resources are not rewriting

Tags: wordpress, cdn

I have a working Wordpress site, and an AWS Cloudfront distribution to make server it faster.

For this I use W3TC, and configured its CDN setting.

While it mostly works great, some resource files are simply don't get rewritten:

```
wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=6.4.1
```

I could turn on debug mode, but it doesn't show the reason on why these files are not being overwritten with my CDN link.

W3TC config:

[image]

[image]

How could I force this file to be loaded via CDN?

I also tried to add it manually:

[image]

But it always loads from the original location and not from CDN.

All other 100+ resources are loaded from CDN.